# Rename file in bash script

Tags: bash, file, rename

I found that how to rename multiple file in bash script had been already asked. I have checked all answers. However, I could not solve my problem.
I would like to find all files with certain name in a given directory. Then, I would like to rename all files accordingly. I need all diectories starting with 'lattice' and also need files starting with 'POSCAR.' in lattice directories. I have many directories starting with 'lattice'

This is what I have tried. Bash gives error like "they are the same files"

```
match=POSCAR.
replace=POSCAR
for D in *lattice*
do echo "$D"
  for file in $(find $D -name "*POSCAR*")
  do
    echo "$file"
    src=$file
    tgt=$(echo $file | sed -e "s/*$match*/$replace/")
    fnew= `echo $file | sed 's/*POSCAR/POSCAR/'`  
    mv $src $tgt
  done
done
```

Comment: It's a little obvious but I think you shouldn't allow a space between the value and declarator sign (=). Also, place your variables between quotes to prevent possible further expansion with IFS. Use $() over pairs of backquotes as well as it is preferred with Bash/POSIX stuffs.

Comment: You didn't use your fnew variable there as well. You just assigned a value to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this

```
find lattice* -type f -name 'POSCAR.*' \
    -exec bash -c 'echo mv -iv "$0" "${0/POSCAR./POSCAR}"' '{}' \;
```

Remove the [echo](/questions/tagged/echo) when you're sure it does what you want. Note this assumes, you don't have some `POSCAR.` directory earlier in your path.

Not also, `*WORD*` matches files with `WORD` anywhere. `WORD*` matches files that start with `WORD`. Also, I'm assuming you mean that `POSCAR.*` are regular files (i.e. not directories or symlinks, so I included the `-type f`.

Comment: waht it does ib bash :mv -iv --lattice_1.1/POSCAR.1.1 lattice_1.1/POSCAR1.1. it does not change the name of file to POSCAR

Comment: @user2100161 So you want `POSCAR.1.1 -> POSCAR` or `POSCAR.1.1 -> POSCAR1.1`?

Comment: @user2100161 If you want `POSCAR.1.1 -> POSCAR` just replace `"${0/POSCAR./POSCAR}"` with `"${0/POSCAR.*/POSCAR}"`, and again remove the `echo` if you really want them to be renamed.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps [`rename`](http://man.he.net/man1/rename) tool may help you.

```
rename 's/POSCAR\./POSCAR/' *lattice*
```

Comment: Think you have the wrong `rename` linked. That should be the one that [comes with the perl libraries](http://man.he.net/man1/rename). Not the one that for some reason comes with util-linux despite no one ever using it.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is the right `find` syntax and the right [bash string manipulation](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html)

```
while read -d $'\0' -r file; do

  # // replaces all matches. If you want only the first one use /
  newname=${file//POSCAR./POSCAR} 
  mv "$file" "$newname"

done < <(find \( -ipath '*/lattice*' -and -iname 'POSCAR.*' \) -print0)
```

Comment: I tried your solution. bash gives error'find: invalid expression; you have used a binary operator '-and' with nothing before it.'how can we resolve this.Thanks

Comment: @user2100161 What OS are you on? What version of bash do you have? What version of find?

Comment: OS is UBUNTU. bash version is 4.1.5.thanks. find 4.4.2